# If else not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

So I made page with unban request and in users table I save if user already sent request or not so I don't have multiple unban requests from one user.Now when I check if user sent request it's not working.In database it stands 0 and it's still showing me error pop out.
Here is code, thanks for help in advance

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-unban_req']))
{   
    if($unban_sent = 0)//THIS IS WHERE I CHECK
    {
        //MY THIGNS HERE
        if($connection ->query($unbanquery) === TRUE) 
        {           
          //MY THIGNS HERE
            if ($connection->query($sentquery) === TRUE) 
            {
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo $connection->error;
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else  // AND I GET THIS ERROR EVEN IF IT STANDS 0 IN DATABASE
    {
        echo "Unban already sent!";
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you get the value of the variable `$unban_sent` from? I see no assignment to the variable

Comment: comparison should be `==` instead of `=`. That could be why you always get `0`

Comment: if($unban_sent = 0) its assigning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing the values, this is assigning the values:

```
if($unban_sent = 0) // assigning values
```

This should be:

```
if($unban_sent == 0) // comparing values
```

**Basic Example:**

Lets say,

`1 = 1` its assigning 
`1 == 1` its checking the condition will return TRUE.

For more help: **[PHP Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)**

Answer (score 0):

In line 3 you missed a `=` for comparision. Instead, you set `$unban_set` to `0`

Try it with this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-unban_req']))
{   
    if($unban_sent == 0) //<- Now you are checking it here
    {
        //MY THIGNS HERE
        if($connection ->query($unbanquery) === TRUE) 
        {           
          //MY THIGNS HERE
            if ($connection->query($sentquery) === TRUE) 
            {
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo $connection->error;
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else  // AND I GET THIS ERROR EVEN IF IT STANDS 0 IN DATABASE
    {
        echo "Unban already sent!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using this code which is wrong.

```
$unban_sent = 0
```

`$unban_sent = 0` means to assign `0` to `$unban_sent`

---

It should be:

```
$unban_sent == 0
```

`$unban_sent == 0` means `$unban_sent` is equal to 0

---

`==` is for **comparison**, `=` is for **assignment**, and `===` is for **identical** or **same type**.

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.